# C++11 lambda doesn't take const variable by reference, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, g++, clang++

Trying to compile this code:

```
const int a = 1;
auto lambda = [&]() {
  &a;
};
lambda();
```

On clang++ everything is fine, but g++ gives an error:

> error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand

I haven't found anything explaining such behavior. Is it a bug in g++? Or does clang++ miss something?

Comment: Have you tried with the latest `gcc-4.9`?

Comment: Nope, only 4.8.1 is available on my repo.

Comment: Just file a bug. If it's not valid, they'll invalidate, better than asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's considered to be a bug in g++: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58894

According to comments, it lasts from GCC 4.5.4 and, at that moment, not fixed in GCC 4.9.0.